# is it posible to have 'if object is nothing or blank' test in one line?

Tags: vb.net

If I have a test that tests both for object being nothing AND blank at the same time is it posible to have this on one line of code ?

```
 If  Not DataGridView5.EditingControl is nothing and Trim(DataGridView5.EditingControl.Text) = "") Then
```

the above example is typical what Im looking for, as if the Editing control is nothing then the code crashes on the editing control text test is there any way to write this so that it dosent without having to write multiple if thens ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found AndAlso and implemented it before I received the below suggestions.

```
(Not DataGridView5.EditingControl Is Nothing AndAlso Trim(DataGridView5.EditingControl.Text = ""))
```

so the test does not proceed past the ' nothing ' test which is what I want as either nothing or a blank need to trigger. I never knew that ANDALSO existed, could have saved me a lot of code writing !

Comment: Did you also discover OrElse which shortcircuits on a True first test? Equally helpful in the right place. These weren't always there in VB, which may be why you didn't know about them.

Comment: no I did not, excellent to know and gold when its just the right thing to use to solve a problem. To think the code I wasted writing 2 stage checks for is it nothing and then dose it have a value ! Thank you .

Answer (score 1):

I have not tested this but this might help,

```
Dim valid as Boolean = If(DataGridView5.EditingControl is Nothing,False,If(String.IsNullOrEmpty(DataGridView5.EditingControl.Text),False,True))
```

So, if EditingControl is neither Nothing and not Empty, valid should be "True"

Answer (score 0):

Yes, make a function that wraps up that logic and call it.  [Extension methods](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384936.aspx) are particularly succinct.

To automate this process based on a changing property, I went through [Reflection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173183.aspx) to get type and property information.  If your only goal is shortening code and making it more readable, this solution will be fine.  You can of course always shorten the name of the function if it's still too long.

```
Public Module ExtensionMethods

    <System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Extension>
    Public Function SafeIsNullOrWhitespaceProp(Of T As New)(obj As T, propName As String) As Boolean
        If obj Is Nothing Then
            Return True
        End If

        Dim [property] = GetType(T).GetProperty(propName)
        If [property].PropertyType <> GetType(String) Then
            Return False
        End If

        'or throw ArgumentException if you really want to ward off misuse
        Dim value As String = DirectCast([property].GetValue(obj), String)
        Return [String].IsNullOrWhiteSpace(value)
    End Function
End Module
```

This extension method is called just like this:

```
DataGridView5.EditingControl.SafeIsNullOrWhitespaceProp("Name")
```

A [.NET Fiddle in VB](https://dotnetfiddle.net/MF6SjW).
(Note I created the logic for this in C# and used a VB converter, so there may be some unintended bugs.  Here's the original [.NET Fiddle C#](https://dotnetfiddle.net/21C9U7))

Comment: Note that [String].IsNullOrWhiteSpace() is .NET 4.0 and above only.

Answer (score 0):

(Not DataGridView5.EditingControl Is Nothing AndAlso Trim(DataGridView5.EditingControl.Text = String.Empty))